# CATransform3DMakeRotation symbol not found

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, quartz-graphics

I've included:

```
#import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h"
```

but when I try to build, I get the error mentioned in the title.  Is there something else I need to do to tell XCode to include the framework?

The code where I use it is:

```
CALayer *layer = paperView.layer;
CATransform3D rotation = CATransform3DMakeRotation(1, 0, 0, 1);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it working by:

In the "Groups & Files" pane on the left:

Right click Frameworks -> Add -> Existing Frameworks

and add QuartzCore.Framework

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the CoreGraphics.framework to you project.

Right click Frameworks -> Add -> Existing Frameworks.

Comment: Thanks, this was close, but I didn't see this before I corrected the problem with the answer I posted.  This would have been magic if I had seen it earlier.